# Get search query params in RootLayout Nextjs13 app

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have used nextjs13.

Following is my folder structure

```
  app 
    layout.tsx
    page.tsx
```

I want to catch the search query params from Layout server component.

```
    const Layout = async ({
      children,
      searchParams,
    }: {
children:ReactNode;
      searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
    }) => {

   }
```

anyone please help.